# TSlint inline errors

Tags: tslint

I have tslint.json setup and the editor I use is VSCode. I am required to run the command `tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json` every time I need to see errors associated with Type-checking (like typedef) and they show up only in the terminal.

Is there a way to have them show up in the code within the TS file as a red squiggly without using the VScode tslint plugin?